# Unit test fails on wtforms

Tags: python, python-unittest, flask-wtforms, wtforms

When using pytest to do unittesting on posting datas to flask wtforms, the form's fileds' data is always `''`, which seems like the data is not properly "posted" to the forms, and it cause the `form.validate_on_submit()` will always return `False`. I've disabled the `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` when testing.

I've made a minimal project to demonstrate this problem. I did not include database here because database works fine in my real project.

This minimal project structure is here:

```
.
├── app.py
├── templates
│   └── login.html
└── tests
    └── test_login.py
```

test_login.py:

```py
import unittest
from flask import current_app
from app import create_app


class BasicsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_app_exists(self):
        self.assertFalse(current_app is None)

    def test_home_page(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_login(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            '/login', data={
                'username': 'a',
                'password': 'a'
            })
```

app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, Blueprint
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import PasswordField, StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length

bp = Blueprint('myapp', __name__)


@bp.route('/')
def home():
    return 'hello'


@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(prefix='form-login-')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Log In')


def create_app():
    app = Flask('__name__')
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that when your wtforms have the `prefix` property, the way you post data should change.

As you see, the form I use is `form = LoginForm(prefix='form-login-')`, and the way I post the data to the form is

```py
response = self.client.post(
            '/login', data={
                'username': 'a',
                'password': 'a'
            })
```

It will not pass data properly until you add the `prefix` you use in the form to the data dictionary, like this:

```py
response = self.client.post(
            '/login', data={
                'form-login-username': 'a',
                'form-login-password': 'a'
            })
```

Everything works fine now!

But if you want to get the form field data, you should still use `form.username.data`, without any `prefix`.